# Gradle task fails to open a jdbc connection due to driver not found issue

Tags: gradle, jdbc, groovy

I want to connect to a database in one of my gradle tasks. Sadly this fails because of the following exception:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2432/postgres

But I am quite confident that the driver is in the classpath as I am importing and printing the the class which works fine. So what do I do wrong here?

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "5.2.4"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

import java.sql.DriverManager
import org.postgresql.Driver
def postgresServer = null
def postgresUser = 'postgres'
def postgresPassword = 'postgres'
def postgresPort = 2432
def databaseName = "dbmanager"

task connect() {
    println(Class.forName('org.postgresql.Driver'))
    def connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2432/postgres")
}
```

Comment: that's because jdbc drivers must be loaded with system classloader. move this code to groovy script and run it from gradle. or just use groovy instead of gradle..

Comment: hmm but how is flyway doing it then?